# Merging Woocommerce Cart and ckeckout templates issue

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, cart

I need to customize `Woocommerce` cart and add checkout form to cart page. 
I tried to paste code from form-checkout.php to cart.php but it doesn't work. I have an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
>   get_checkout_fields() on null

As I understand I just called to undefined function but how can I define it?
If somebody is familiar with customizing `woocommerce` templates please help me.
Also would be very pleasant if someone shares some useful links about customizing `woocommerce`, I have already read a lot about it, but most of it were useless.

My code from cart.php is below.

Thank you in advance!

```
<?php
/**
 * Cart Page
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/cart.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.1.0
 */ 
?>
                    <h2 class="main-h2">
          <span class="thin">В </span>
          КОРЗИНЕ
        </h2>

<? if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

wc_print_notices();

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' ); ?>

<form class="woocommerce-cart-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ); ?>" method="post">
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_table' ); ?>

    <table class="shop_table shop_table_responsive cart woocommerce-cart-form__contents" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="product-remove">&nbsp;</th>
                <th class="product-thumbnail">&nbsp;</th>
                <th class="product-name"><?php _e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <th class="product-price"><?php _e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <th class="product-quantity"><?php _e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <th class="product-subtotal"><?php _e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_contents' ); ?>

            <?php
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                $_product   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
                    $product_permalink = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', $_product->is_visible() ? $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) : '', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                    ?>
                    <tr class="woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item <?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">

                        <td class="product-remove">
                            <?php
                                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf(
                                    '

                                    <a href="%s" class="pi-close-btn" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s">&times;>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 357 357" style="enable-background:new 0 0 357 357;" xml:space="preserve">
                  <g>
                    <g>
                        <polygon points="357,35.7 321.3,0 178.5,142.8 35.7,0 0,35.7 142.8,178.5 0,321.3 35.7,357 178.5,214.2 321.3,357 357,321.3     214.2,178.5   " fill="#ffffff"/>
                    </g>
                  </g>
                </svg>
              </a>',
                                    esc_url( WC()->cart->get_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
                                    __( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
                                    esc_attr( $product_id ),
                                    esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
                                ), $cart_item_key );
                            ?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="product-thumbnail">
                            <?php
                                $thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                                if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
                                    echo $thumbnail;
                                } else {
                                    printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $thumbnail );
                                }
                            ?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="product-name" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                            <?php
                                if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
                                    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) . '&nbsp;';
                                } else {
                                    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $_product->get_name() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                                }

                                // Meta data
                                echo WC()->cart->get_item_data( $cart_item );

                                // Backorder notification
                                if ( $_product->backorders_require_notification() && $_product->is_on_backorder( $cart_item['quantity'] ) ) {
                                    echo '<p class="backorder_notification">' . esc_html__( 'Available on backorder', 'woocommerce' ) . '</p>';
                                }
                            ?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="product-price" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                            <?php
                                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                            ?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="product-quantity" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                            <?php
                                if ( $_product->is_sold_individually() ) {
                                    $product_quantity = sprintf( '1 <input type="hidden" name="cart[%s][qty]" value="1" />', $cart_item_key );
                                } else {
                                    $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
                                        'input_name'  => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
                                        'input_value' => $cart_item['quantity'],
                                        'max_value'   => $_product->get_max_purchase_quantity(),
                                        'min_value'   => '0',
                                    ), $_product, false );
                                }

                                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item );
                            ?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="product-subtotal" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                            <?php
                                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $cart_item['quantity'] ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                            ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_contents' ); ?>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="6" class="actions">

                    <?php if ( wc_coupons_enabled() ) { ?>
                        <div class="coupon">
                            <label for="coupon_code"><?php _e( 'Coupon:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label> <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" id="coupon_code" value="" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Coupon code', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /> <input type="submit" class="button" name="apply_coupon" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
                            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_coupon' ); ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <input type="submit" class="button" name="update_cart" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Update cart', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />

                    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_actions' ); ?>

                    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-cart' ); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_contents' ); ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_table' ); ?>
</form>

<div class="cart-collaterals">
    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_cart_collaterals hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_cross_sell_display
         * @hooked woocommerce_cart_totals - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals' );
    ?>
</div>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart' ); ?>


<?php If ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

wc_print_notices();

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', $checkout );

// If checkout registration is disabled and not logged in, the user cannot checkout

?>

<?php if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

wc_print_notices();

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', $checkout ); ?>

<form name="checkout" method="post" class="checkout woocommerce-checkout" action="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() ); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <?php if ( $checkout->get_checkout_fields() ) : ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details' ); ?>

        <div class="col2-set" id="customer_details">
            <div class="col-1">
                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_billing' ); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="col-2">
                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_shipping' ); ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <h3 id="order_review_heading"><?php _e( 'Your order', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review' ); ?>

    <div id="order_review" class="woocommerce-checkout-review-order">
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review' ); ?>
    </div>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_order_review' ); ?>

</form>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', $checkout ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) As `$checkout` need to be defined you get this error. It is an instance of the [**`WC_Checkout`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Checkout.html) object.
To define it you will use:

```
$checkout = WC()->checkout;
```

Then now, as **`get_checkout_fields()`** is a method of **`WC_Checkout`**, you will not get any error. To add it in your template, see below…

---

2) Also in your code you have some unnecessary code that **you will need to remove** just under `<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart' ); ?>` (below line 183):

```
<?php If ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

wc_print_notices();

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', $checkout );

// If checkout registration is disabled and not logged in, the user cannot checkout

?>

<?php if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

wc_print_notices();
```

> And you will add instead: `$checkout = WC()->checkout;`

Note: `wc_print_notices();` is already located at the beginning of your code, that's why I remove it.

**This should solve your error issue…**